# Trying to stream a PDF file from server1 to server2 getting file is “damaged file”

Tags: asp.net, file-io, pdf-generation

i have pdf and doc file in server1 folder path(d:\files\a.pdf) now i want to read file  located in server1 from
server2 and show in popup with option save and open.

below  code i  written in server1:

If File.Exists(d:\files\a.pdf) Then
            Dim fs As New FileStream(isFullFilePath & filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read)
            'Try
            Try

```
            fs = New FileStream(isFullFilePath & filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read)
            '        Catch ex As FileNotFoundException
            'UploadDoc.PostedFile.SaveAs(UploadDoc.PostedFile.FileName)
            '    fs = New FileStream(UploadDoc.PostedFile.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read)
            'End Try

            Dim byteArray(fs.Length) As Byte
            fs.Read(byteArray, 0, fs.Length)

            Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
            Response.BinaryWrite(byteArray)

        Catch ex As Exception
        Finally
            fs.Close()

        End Try
```

and in server2 :

```
            Dim objHttpWebRequest As HttpWebRequest
            Dim objHttpWebResponse As HttpWebResponse
            objHttpWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(DownloadURL)
            objHttpWebRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post

            objHttpWebRequest.Timeout = 600000
            objHttpWebRequest.MaximumResponseHeadersLength = 80000000
            objHttpWebResponse = objHttpWebRequest.GetResponse()

            If objHttpWebResponse.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK Then

                'Dim dataStream As Stream = objHttpWebResponse.GetResponseStream

                Dim BArr(objHttpWebResponse.ContentLength - 1) As Byte
                'Dim fs As StreamWriter

                'Request.InputStream.Read(BArr, 0, objHttpWebResponse.ContentLength)
                objHttpWebResponse.GetResponseStream.Read(BArr, 0, objHttpWebResponse.GetResponseStream.ReadByte)

                Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
                Response.Charset = "UTF-8"
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" & strFileNameID(0))
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", objHttpWebResponse.ContentLength)
                Response.BinaryWrite(BArr)
```

but getting error PDF is damage,after 8 hour spending.....

Please help me

Thanks in advance
Raghvendra

Answer (score 0):

Has your web site been enabled to use compression? I don't know about service to service, but I know that compression can break pdf's to browsers - you might be suffering from the same issue.

Here's a link to someone suffering from the compression issue:

http://www.griffincaprio.com/blog/2006/11/iis-http-compression-and-streaming-pdfs-dont-do-it.html